# Batch crop and center photos by trimming whitespace

Tags: adobe-photoshop, batch-processing, crop, script

Processing large amounts of product images shot on white backdrops is very time consuming and seems like the perfect job for an app/script, but I cannot see anything available that can do this.

If I were able to create a photoshop script it would (presuming a bunch of layers as smart objects)

1. Create a rectangular selection around the object in the image using a simple luminance threshold value to determine what is object and what is backdrop.
2. Scale and centre the image so that this bounding box fills the canvas, with a user definable amount of padding.

The image dimensions need to remain constant for all images (or at least the aspect ratio)

(I don't want to 'straighten' anything)

I've attempted to make a start at this with extend script, but I can't see any way to achieve step 1.

Is anyone aware of an existing app or script that can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you need a script. How about recording an action like this:

- Convert your image to a *Smart Object* if it isn't already.
- Add a *Threshold Adjustment Layer* and choose your wanted threshold.
- Use *Image > Trim* and probably set *Based On* to *Top Left Pixel Color* to crop the image to the object.
- Delete the adjustment layer.
- To scale the image to the wanted dimensions first use *File > Automate > Fit Image* where you enter the wanted dimensions *minus* the padding to scale the image proportionally to fit inside the wanted dimensions. Then use *Image > Canvas Size* with those same dimensions to extend the canvas to the wanted dimensions.
- Use *Image > Canvas Size* with *Relative* checked to add padding to the image.

The image needs to be a Smart Object. Otherwise *Trim* would delete the cropped pixels, and the added padding would have to be a solid color.

If you want to do some manipulations to the "mask" before cropping it might be easier to *Copy Merged*, *Paste* and then work destructively on the pasted image which you of course delete in the end.

For example, you might have some stray pixels below the threshold which will ruin the crop. These can be eliminated by using *Filter > Blur > Gaussian Blur* before using *Threshold* or by shrinking the black area afterwards using *Filter > Other > Maximum*.

Comment: Thanks, this is a good start, but how is 'scale your image' step to be performed now that 'trim' has created a canvas with arbitrary dimensions. 'Canvas Size' will generate inconsistent padding, Image size with specific dimensions will stretch it.

Comment: OK, added method to scale image to a certain size.

Comment: Ok thats close, I dont know how I missed 'Automate > Fit' before. But how to have everything in a single document as layers (as in my presumption in OP) ? This is important as the auto process Is imperfect and needs manual helping and comparison to other layers. If I batch this as PSD and then 'Load files into Stack', it rasterises the smart objects which is no good.  If I instead add 'Duplicate Layer' to the action and target a new document, all the layers will have the same name, so I can't export them out without forgetting what their original names were. Have I missed anything?

Comment: Can't you just record the action and apply it to multiple files using *File > Automate > Batch*? Or if it's not too many files, assign a function key to the action, open all the files and apply the action for each individual file. (Remember to backup your files!)

Comment: Yes I'm doing batch, thats what I was referring to when I say the resulting files are imperfect. Loading each file as new seperate document after the batch and adjusting and resaving adds up to about as much time as doing it all manually in the first place. Even if there could be a way to get the resulting files post batch, all into a new document as layers - smart objects intact -- then this would be then still an advantage. But it seems there's no way.

Comment: Photoshop CC has a "Select > Subject" function which might help for automating tasks like this.

Comment: I don't understand why batching should flatten your documents. Or why you should have to make new documents. Do we agree that the action I describe doesn't ruin your layers? Batching should simply apply that action to the documents of your choice with all the original layers intact.

Comment: I've accepted is as the answer as it does satisfy the title of the question. Batching doesn't flatten the documents if they are saved PSDs. But this process gives rough approximation that could be nudged/scaled manually quite easily if they were smart object layers in a single document. But 'Load files into Stack', that could achieve this (post batch), does flatten them. I just have to accept there really is no way to do this in a fashion that affectively cuts the time down for a large folder of images that need to have visually consistent cropping.